# Dart DevTools showing "Connect to a running app"

Tags: debugging, flutter, dart

I can't start the Dart Dev Tools in VS Code, when I launch in debugging mode it opens a chrome window says `Connect to a running app
Enter a port or URL to a running Dart or Flutter application.`

When I hover over the `Dart DevTools` button, it shows a port but I still can't connect to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22):

Start your flutter app with `--observatory-port` option. For example,

```
flutter run --observatory-port=9200
```

Once the app starts, you’ll see a message in your terminal that looks like:

```
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9200/Swm0bjIe0ks=/
```

Paste the URL you got from running your app `(http://127.0.0.1:9200/Swm0bjIe0ks=/)` into the connect dialog to connect your app to DevTools.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still does not work for me. When I paste the URL I get a "Unable to connect to 'http://127.0.0.1:39044/IHV09ogAdcs=/'" error.

Comment: maybe because the "http:" is missing ;) ?

Comment: How can we get this url later e.g. after I cleared my console?

Answer (score 7):

On Visual Studio Code: click the letter (v) while the app is running. that's it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Same for IntelliJ, thank you!

Comment: That was quick and easy +1

Answer (score 6):

Hi run your app on emulator or real device.
On bottom of android studio you will find a run tab
on run tab there will be a message like below:
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54675/CPu_ErpGRaw=/ws

copy (ws://127.0.0.1:54675/CPu_ErpGRaw=/ws) and paste it on Dart DevTools input field.
It will be connected to your running device or emulator

Answer (score 3):

In Run flutter in Terminal with port you want. It can 9200 or 9300 or 9301 etc
flutter run --observatory-port=9200

On the logcat you will see message look like
"An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9200/Swm0bjIe0ks=/"

After that copy and past url (http://127.0.0.1:9200/Swm0bjIe0ks=/) to dialog connect your app to DevTools

Answer (score 0):

In my case the above answers did not  work due I had another problem:  PATH:  the enviroment variables. This was because I couldn't execute flutter command in the terminal at my folder app project , so enviroment variables at system level it's necessary and I was doing this at user level for Windows. So I run flutter doctor o whatever to see if alredy the path was working and   then   I used the  answer of @Hayeong Choi.